# Extracting a polygonal part of a sphere's surface

Tags: three.js

In Three.JS, I have a Sphere object representing Earth. I'm interested in creating a mesh that represents the surface of the sphere over a particular region.

Let's say, for example, that I want a representation of Australia. I want to take the globe and run a knife across the border of Australia, slicing the continent out of the globe. The end result would be a 3D mesh of Australia, with curvature.

I know that with Earcut I can get a nice 2D triangulation for Australia. I thought about taking all the points from the triangulation and projecting them into 3D, but the problem here is that the interior vertices of the triangulation are quite irregular and would not create a nice smooth round mesh. Is there some way of getting a triangulated mesh that has nice evenly-spaced interior vertices? Or is there a better approach to this problem that I'm completely overlooking?